# PyTorch's DataParallel is only using one GPU

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch, gpu

I'm trying to use two GPU's for training a model in PyTorch. I'm using `torch.nn.DataParallel` but for some reason `nvidia-smi` is saying that I'm only using one GPU.

The code is something along the lines of:

```
>>> import torch.nn as nn 
>>> model = SomeModel()
>>> model = nn.DataParallel(model)
>>> model.to('cuda')
```

When I run the program and observe the output of `nvidia-smi`, I only see GPU 0 running. Would anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `devices_ids`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried doing `device_ids=[0, 1]` in the function call, but as far as I know the default is for `nn.DataParallel` to use all available devices. Neither works. :(

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and solved it by realizing I was using it wrong. Maybe this will help someone save some time:

If you wrap your model like `model = nn.DataParallel(model)` it will wrap only the call to exactly this model (call means `model(input)`). So if your model has a linear layer and you now use that directly like `model.my_linear(input)` it will not be wrapped.

If you pass around references to your model instance in your code you may end up with a reference to the unwrapped model which then also will not work.

The easiest test would be to wrap your model immediately before calling it and to check if that works. If it does, your wrapping code before probably has one of the issues above.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `nn.DataParallel(model, [0,1])` in order to use GPU #0 and GPU #1. The call `model.to('cuda')` afterwards is not necessary. You may be tempted to use `nn.DataParallel(model.to('cuda'), [0,1])`, but this [appears unnecessary as well](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-do-we-need-to-send-the-model-to-a-device-if-we-are-using-dataparallel/17321/2).

Answer (score 0):

Note that DataParallel will try to split your input tensor along the first dimension by default. If it's unable to do so (e.g. if the input is not a tensor) it might silently fall back to using a single GPU. For more detail, see https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/while-using-nn-dataparallel-only-accessing-one-gpu/19807/19